# Basic STL string extraction from results obtained from CPPRest libraries (i.e. casablanca)?

Tags: c++, rest, stl, iostream

I'm trying to learn 2 things: 
1) Some basic C++ STL (I'm an old C/C++ coder, trying to learn new stuff)
2) How to access my wunderlist account through REST services using the [CPPRest library](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk).

I have been able to successfully start an oauth2 process with Wunderlist, but to help me understand what's happening and being returned, all I want to do is print result strings. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this. It has something to do with manipulating iostreams, but since I'm new to these, I'm struggling.

Here's a code snippet that successfully gets HTML from an initial Wunderlist response into a streambuf, but I cannot get it into a string for printing (or whatever). Please note that I'm not concerned with doing this asynchronously; therefore, I'm just forcing synchronization via !task.is_done(). Also, if you want to compile and run you'd need to provide your own client_id for Wunderlist, OR use a different service.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/oauth2.h>

using namespace utility;                    // Common utilities like string conversions
using namespace web;                        // Common features like URIs.
using namespace web::http;                  // Common HTTP functionality
using namespace web::http::client;          // HTTP client features
using namespace concurrency::streams;       // Asynchronous streams
using namespace web::http::oauth2::details;

int main()
{
    http_client clientWL(U("https://www.wunderlist.com"));
    uri_builder builderWL(U("oauth/authorize"));
    builderWL.append_query(U("client_id"), U("[myclientid]"));
    builderWL.append_query(U("redirect_uri"), U("http://www.google.com"));
    builderWL.append_query(U("state"), U("Randomish"));

    auto task = clientWL.request(methods::GET, builderWL.to_string());
    while (!task.is_done());

    http_response resp1 = task.get();
    Concurrency::streams::basic_ostream<char> os = Concurrency::streams::container_stream<std::string>::open_ostream();
    Concurrency::streams::streambuf<char> sb = os.streambuf();

    Concurrency::task<size_t> task2 = resp1.body().read_to_end(sb);
    while (!task2.is_done());

    // HOW DO I GET THE RESULTING HTML STRING I CAN PLAINLY SEE IN sb 
    // (VIA A DEBUGGER) INTO THE FOLLOWING STRING OBJECT?
    std::string strResult;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a platform independent way of extracting the string from the `http_response` object:

```
http_response resp1 = task.get();
auto response_string = resp1.extract_string().get();
std::cout << response_string << std::endl; // Will print it to stdout
```

Comment: Ah, that did it. Thank you huu. I can make progress now. However, I still feel like getting the response body via the body() function and then reading it into a streambuf makes sense somehow. I mean what good is populating a streambuf<char> object that I can fill with data but I cannot read back in any way, shape or form? Maybe I just need to spend more time studying streams... sigh...

Comment: Some tasks are more naturally expressed with streams, for instance, [writing to a file](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/78f85545af36da8ddadac15ba4dfb9aece0fbe0c/Release/samples/BingRequest/bingrequest.cpp#L64). If you're simply interested in getting the response string as a plain old string object, then you don't need to mess around with the stream buffer at all. The above sample works just fine if you omit all your lines about the output stream or stream buffer.

Comment: I see. I was basically copying from another sample that did output the result data to a file... thus it used a file stream. Since I didn't want to have to open a file to look at the results, I figured I'd just do the conversion from a filestream to a stringstream, but as you point out, that overcomplicates it. Thanks again.